# Can i use 2 different firebase project with the same package name?

Tags: android, ios, firebase

I have a project available in cloud.developer.com. I realized that i didn't migrated this project to Firebase.

I have accidentally created a new Firebase project one year ago, and used this in production.

Now, i realized some of third party libraries(for using analytics) use the google project number of the project which is available in cloud.developer.com. Thus i MUST now migrate my application available in cloud.developer.com to Firebase. I migrated it. So there are 2 Firebase projects which has the same package name in my account. I cannot delete neither of them because both of them is used in prod. I used google-services.json of the firebase project which i migrated from cloud.developer.com however Firebase integration is unsuccesfull.

Is there a restriction for using 2 different firebase project with same package name?